# Числа считаются равными, если они отличаются не более чем на (10^-12)

Tags: c++, числа

На плоскости заданы три точки А, В и С. Определить, какая из двух последних точек (B или C) расположена ближе к A, и вывести расстояние от этой точки до точки A. Если точки В и С равноудалены от точки А, то вывести также расстояние между этими точками.

**Формат входных данных**

Единственная строка, содержащая шесть действительных чисел, разделенных пробелами, каждое из которых не превышает по модулю 104 - координаты точек А, В, С, соответственно.

**Формат результата**

Вывести одну или две строки. Первая строка содержит единственное число - расстояние от точки А до ближайшей из двух точек (В или С). 
Если точки В и С равноудалены от точки А, то вывести вторую строку, содержащую расстояние между точками В и С. Числа считаются равными, если они отличаются не более чем на 10^-12. Относительная или абсолютная погрешность выводимых значений не должна превышать 10^-6.

Программа корректно выполняет задачу, но на 102 тесте (онлайн) выдает ошибку!
Я предполагаю, что проблема в условии погрешности равенства чисел! *(Числа считаются равными, если они отличаются не более чем на 10^-12.)*

Как ввести условие погрешности, чтобы программа проверяла, если числа отличаются на 10^-12 и далее, то сделать их абсолютно одинаковыми, допустим, до 10^-11 степени?

Comment: С очень большой вероятностью, условие `a_c == a_b` никогда не будет выполнятся. Напишите его правильно.

Comment: Условие a_c == a_b работает, программа на 3-ий if выполняет условие если a_c==a_b и выводит 2 числа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вычитайте и сравнивайте с погрешностью:

```
double eps = 0.0000000001;
...
if (fabs(a - b) < eps)
    // ...
```

`double fabs(double)` — взятие модуля от числа, живет в `<cmath>` (она же `<math.h>`)

Comment: А вообще почему бы вам не сравнивать квадраты расстояний? Точность будет выше, корень не нужен (но такая проверка все равно нужна).

Comment: А мне же все равно надо вывести расстояние от точки до точки.

Comment: А... Ну тогда да, прийдется использовать корень. В любом случае дробные числа сравнивайте модулем, иначе с ними много проблем (хотя с ними и так много проблем).

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 2):

Контролируйте относительную ошибку к большему по модулю числу:

```
if(abs(a - b) < eps * max(abs(a),abs(b)) {
  // ...
}
```